# What are origins of the Laplace variable $s$

Tags: laplace-transform, z-transform

When I learnt the Laplace Transform I was just told the very standard formula that:
$F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) e^{-st} dt$. From this we went on to the table of transforms at its properties and how it is used. Later on we were told that $s=\sigma+j\omega$ and after that when we learnt Z-transform and we were told that the two are related via Discrete Time Fourier Transform.

We were taught that in control theory Laplace Transform helps us to find the poles and zeroes of a system transfer function and find out a lot about its dynamic behaviour. We were also taught how the Z-transform is used in expressing $x[n]$.

Now the problem; We have never been taught what $s$ **really means** and how it is able to do all these things, why $s=\sigma+j\omega$  and what it **really means** when we say that it is related to the Z-transform.

Now my question as already stated, what is this magic $s$ i.e what are its origins?

Comment: The way I think of it is by analogy with the Fourier transform. When solving the wave equation, the solutions are of exponential form. In *nice* situations, these exponentials are simply plane waves. However sometimes one can get evanescent wave solutions. So general solutions are in some way linear combinations of plane waves and these exponentially decaying waves.

Comment: With plane waves, $\omega$ plays the role of frequency - how quickly the function oscillates. Clearly that doesn't really hold in our case. The closest analogy might be to consider $s$ as a "damping" parameter - how quickly the function decays. In regards to the transforms, $\mathcal{F}f(\omega)$ gives us an idea of how loud our signal is for a certain modulating frequency. Likewise, $\mathcal{L}f(s)$ gives us an idea of how loud our signal is for this decaying pitch.

Comment: When you ask "what are its origins", are you asking for historical answer or a conceptual one (i.e. "can the Laplace transform be thought of as a particular case of some more general structure")?

Comment: If someone asks you what is 's' in laplace transform, how would you explain that? I know how to use it. I just don't know what it really is inside.